# Strange behaviour of ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I've just noticed some weird behaviour of inputs being working together with ViewBag.

Let's say I have a simple page with Razor syntax which looks like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    @Html.RadioButton("TEST_NAME", i, null)
}
```

None of the radiobuttons are checked by default.
But when I add something like `@ViewBag.TEST_NAME = 5;` the radiobutton with value 5 will be checked.

So why does ViewBag works like this? What is happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't exactly say that's "weird" behavior. When you use one of the Razor helpers to generate a field based off a string name, it will check a few locations for a potential value for the field: `ViewBag`, `ViewData`, `Model` and `Request`. If any of these has a key/property that matches the string name of the field, it will assume that you intended the field to have that value (i.e., if any of `ViewBag.TEST_NAME`, `ViewData["TEST_NAME"]`, `Model.TEST_NAME` and `Request["TEST_NAME"]` were set to `5`, then that same radio button would be checked).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is part of what the MVC framework does behind the scenes by applying ViewBag properties to your model state. You can use @Html.RadioButtonFor(...) to specify the value be taken from a specific model.